# День недели по дате

Tags: php

Есть массив с датами такого типа 2016-12-15,2016-12-12...
Как определить день недели по дате

```
$days = array(
    'Воскресенье', 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда',
    'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота'
);
foreach( $date_time as $key => $val ) {
   echo($days[(date('w'))] . $val);
}
```

Comment: В чём вопрос то? всё правильно: echo($days[(date('w'))]); выведет, что сегодня четверг. Для другой даты подставляйте её вторым параметром

Answer (score 10):

функция `date()`, которую вы используете имеет два параметра. Первый - строка форматирования, и тут вы правильно используете формат `w`, возвращающий номер дня недели, где 0 соответствует воскресенье.

Вторым параметром является метка времени, по умолчанию этот параметр равен текущему дате и времени. Поэтому вам следует перевести ваши строки дат в `UNIX TIMESTAMP` с помощью соответствующей функции [`strtodate()`](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.strtotime.php). Вот в общем то и все.

```
$dates = ['2016-12-15', '2016-12-25', '2017-01-26'];

$days = [
    'Воскресенье', 'Понедельник', 'Вторник', 'Среда',
    'Четверг', 'Пятница', 'Суббота'
];

foreach($dates as $d){
    print_r([ 
       'date' => $d, 
       'dayOfWeek' => $days[ date("w", strtotime($d) )]
    ]);
}
```

Comment: спасибо вам большое, разобрался